# Shelling an item from a list item

Tags: c#, list, linq, selenium

I am automating some website and I got stuck on such a case. I have a list created, everything is great for me, it has 24 elements. These are products from the store, containing their picture, name, price, etc. But now I need to take two things from the first element and display in the console, namely name and price. Is anyone able to suggest something? I sit and thinks but nothing comes out. All I managed to do was send everything for 1 item.

I tried resolve that with some Linq but without success.

```
public List<string> ListOfElements()
{
    var elements = new List<string>();

    IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> listElements = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".category-list div[class='cat-prod-row js_category-list-item js_clickHashData js_man-track-event ']");

    foreach (IWebElement element in listElements)
    {
        elements.Add(element.Text);
    }

    return elements;
}

public void DisplayFirstElement()
{
    var firstElement = ListOfElements();
    Console.WriteLine(firstElement[0]);
}
```

I want get name and price of first element and then assert that price for that is greater than 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You´re flattening all the elements properties into a single collection of strings. Thus you´re losing any relationship between those strings. It´s hard to say what the 22rd element within thhat list actually is: is it a price? A name? Something completey different? To which item does it actually belong?

Instead you should just return a list of entities and then print the properties of the very first **entitity**:

```
public List<IWebElement> ListOfElements()
{
    var elements = new List<string>();
    return listElements = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".category-list div[class='cat-prod-row js_category-list-item js_clickHashData js_man-track-event ']");
}

public void DisplayFirstElement()
{
    var allElements = ListOfElements();
    var firstElement = allElements.First();
    Console.WriteLine("FirstName: " + firstElement.Name + " Price: " + firstElement.Price);
}
```

Of course this assumes your `IWebElement` has a `Name`- and a `Price`-property.